# Is there any possibility to trigger an AWS Lambda function before saving to S3?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a file that i want to upload. But before saving it into my S3 bucket i want to make some processing. I thought that it would be a good idea to create an AWS Lambda function that would be triggered once the file upload to s3 will occur.

I tried to figure out if the Lambda function can be triggered before the upload and i could not find much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bypass S3 and upload it directly to Lambda, but then you would be limited by Lambda's 6MB payload limit.

The typical pattern for this sort of thing, is to upload to one bucket, have S3 trigger Lambda to process the file, and then have Lambda write the "processed" file to a different bucket (or different folder in the same bucket).

Comment: you will want to account for duplicates with this pattern because S3 trigger has "at least once" guarantee so it could trigger the lambda multiple times. In such an event you would want to make sure that you don't write duplicate files (if that's undesirable)